# Android ROM building. Issue with JDK

Tags: android, java

The other day I was trying to build Android ROM using the AOSP code. I had setup the environment according to the steps mentioned in their guide but I keep getting this error during the same

```
Checking build tools versions...

You are attempting to build with an unsupported JDK. This build requires OpenJDK, but you are using: java version "1.7.0_55" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode).

Please follow the machine setup instructions at https://source.android.com/source/download.html

build/core/main.mk:197: * stop. Stop.
```

I've already installed openjdk-7 on my machine and have already update-alternative to this openjdk. But nothing I do seems to be solving this error.

Hoping someone could help me here..

Comment: I assume this is Linux, so what does `which javac` output?

Comment: @nizammoidu : The documentation explicitely mentions that only openJdk is supported.

Comment: @Mgamerz : the output is `/usr/bin/javac`

Comment: I haven't compiled pure aosp, but I have home build for both  Omni ROM as well as Cyanogen, both are building fine with jdk 1.6 ( not java 1.7 )

Comment: @nizammoidu ok.. I've tried it with Oracle jdk 7.. it didnt work. Let me try it with java 6.